# generate edit and delete button at run time an handle the click event in datagridview using c# for windows application

Tags: c#, datagridview, windows

Please look for the code, Here need a processed way for the problem mention in the question.

```
 private void addBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {


        try
        {


            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(comboBox2.Text, textBox6.Text, textBox7.Text, textBox2.Text,textBox3.Text,textBox4.Text,textBox5.Text);
            if (dataGridView1 != null)
            {

                for (int count = 0; (count <= (dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2)); count++)
                {

                    dataGridView1.Rows[count].HeaderCell.Value = string.Format((count + 1).ToString(), "0");

                }                   

            }
```

//how to know which button is pressed i.e edit or delete
//and how to know which rows button is pressed and fetch that row data when
//edit button is pressed into another windows form and when i press update button
//from edit form then data must be change on the same row of datagridview whos
 //edit button is pressed

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {      



    }




 //this is how i added button


 Editlink.UseColumnTextForButtonValue=true;

        Editlink.HeaderText = "Edit";
        Editlink.DataPropertyName = "lnkColumn";
        Editlink.Text = "Edit";
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(Editlink);     

        Deletelink.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
        Deletelink.HeaderText = "delete";
        Deletelink.DataPropertyName = "lnkColumn";
        Deletelink.Text = "Delete";           
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(Deletelink);
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include clear explanation what you are trying to achieve, what you have done, what isn't working etc.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen edit and delete button is added to the datagridview but i want to know which row button is pressed

Answer (score 0):

It's in the event object argument `e`: [DataGridViewCellEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcelleventargs(v=vs.110).aspx)

You can use `e.ColumnIndex` and `e.RowIndex`

Then, to get the row, just do:

```
var row = (DataGridRow)dataGridView1.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(e.RowIndex);
```